# How to install gitolite3 on ubuntu server LTS 14

Tags: ssh, git

I am trying to install Gitolite3 on Ubuntu server LTS 14 x64, using the [git docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite).

First I created a user called `git` as :

```
sudo adduser \
--system --shell /bin/bash --gecos\ 
'Git SCM' --group --disabled-password git
Adding system user `git' (UID 120) ...
Adding new group `git' (GID 129) ...
Adding new user `git' (UID 120) with group `git' ...
Creating home directory `/home/git' ...
```

Then I generated the keys:

```
wdd@ubuntu-server:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/wdd/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/wdd/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/wdd/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
24:76:b9:d1:15:63:71:00:5b:73:96:29:e2:be:4d:63 wdd@ubuntu-server
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|          ..X++o |
|         o.=.*o  |
|      o =.o. .   |
|     . + o.      |
|        S.       |
|          . E    |
|           = .   |
|          . .    |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Then executed the following commands:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
$ gitolite/install -ln
    # assumes $HOME/bin exists and is in your $PATH
$ gitolite setup -pk $HOME/.ssh/auhtroized_keys
```

And this should be the default setting of the gitolite should be ok.

So I go on my windows client machine and want to clone the `gitolite-admin` repo by:

```
git clone git@gitserver:gitolite-admin
```

But it asks me for password,

```
wdd@MUSAHAIDARI-PC /c/Users/wdd
$ git clone git@gitserver:gitolite-admin
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
git@gitserver's password:
```

Here I think we are not supposed to be asked for password, if so what is the password? Since I have not set any password.

I need to mention that I could SSH without password from my PC to Linux-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to the problem. It seemed that git could not find the private keys to login, so I created `~/.ssh/config` containing:

```
Host gitbox
    User git
    Hostname 192.168.0.103
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite
```

Of course you need to change the credentials. Then `gitbox` is used for loggin in credentials.

```
 git clone gitbox:gitolite-admin
```

The problem is solved. Also please keep in mind for each new user, a new entry in this file will be created to link the key files.